# Converting funny, special Latin characters to unicode (foreign characters)

Tags: python, unicode, character-encoding, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape a website that has content in Hebrew.

The Hebrew portions of the site however are appearing like

```
úåìåòô
```

How do I convert these characters into their proper letters?

I am using Python with BeautifulSoup

Comment: BeautifulSoup used the wrong codec to decode the page. How do you load the HTML, using `urllib2.urlopen()` or a different method? The webpage most likely sets the correct codec in the HTTP response headers.

Comment: Yes, I'm using that function - followed by `read()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give BeautifulSoup the right codec to use, because otherwise make an educated guess and get it wrong (some of the time).

If you are using `urllib2` to load the page, you can pass along any encoding the server set with:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.read(),
                     from_encoding =response.info().getparam('charset'))
```

See the [encodings section](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#encodings) of the BeautifulSoup documentation.

Comment: there is no `get_param()`, use `getparam()` instead

Comment: In Python 2, [there is](http://docs.python.org/3/library/mimetools.html#mimetools.Message.getparam). But in Python 3, it was renamed, which is why I get it wrong sometimes. :-P

Comment: The question has no [tag:Python-3.x] tag therefore Python 2 code should be shown by default i.e., if you use Python 3 code then mention it explicitely. btw, you meant the opposite i.e., `getparam()` in Python 2 and `get_param()` in Python 3

Comment: In Python 2, there is **not** (`get_param()`).

Answer (score 1):

According to the web site [Standard Encodings](http://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings)

> cp424 EBCDIC-CP-HE, IBM424    Hebrew
>   cp856                     Hebrew
>   cp862         862, IBM862 Hebrew
>   cp1255    windows-1255    Hebrew 
>   iso8859_8 iso-8859-8, hebrew  Hebrew

Comment: I think cp1255 is more likely to be found in the wild.